# Jasmine Test Case for Angular 2- Navigating to other page

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing test case for angular 2 code using jasmine. I am trying to navigate back to the login page once the user logs out. How can I test the page location?

Answer (score 5):

All you really need to do is test that the router navigate method is called with the correct argument (i.e. the route of the login page). Trying to test an actual navigation could cause more side effects than required for a unit test.

To check that the `Router.navigate` method is called, simply use a stub and spy on it.

```
@Component({})
class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  logout() {
    this.router.navigate(['/login'])
  }
}

let routerStub;

beforeEach(() => {
  routerStub = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate');
  }
  TestBed.configureTestModule({
    declaration: [ SomeComponent ],
    providers: [
      { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub }
    ]
  });
});

it('it should navigate to login after user logs out', () => {
  let component = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent).componentInstance;
  component.logout();

  expect(routerStub.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/login']);
})
```

Comment: I am not using Router. Instead, using NavController. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Create a stub for the NavController and spy on the `push` method or `setRoot`. which ever one you are using

Comment: `let nav = { setRoot: jasmine.createSpy('setRoot') }`

Comment: Can you explain through an example? I am completely a newbie! The logout component has just one function which deletes the data.

Comment: Can you post your code. Without it, I can only guess what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

The Angular team has worked hard to incorporate testing into all native aspects of the angular environment. If you are using the native angular router then they have built testing for you to use. check out this [BLOG](https://developers.livechatinc.com/blog/testing-angular-2-apps-routeroutlet-and-http/). If you are not using the angular router, then you're on your own I think.